# Autologin after the first time with ionic 2 and inappBrowser

Tags: cordova, authentication, ionic2, local-storage, inappbrowser

at the time I'm a trainee at some company.

My task for this time is it to develop an app for them. I have to use Ionic 2 for this.

In this app, I have to call the in-app-browser. In that browser, I come to a login page.
Now I want, that after the first login, my login data get saved.

So that, if I close and open the app, I don't have to give in my login again.

Is there a way to do this with Ionic 2?

Thank you in advance

*edit*

I think I want to change my approach to this.

So I set the required data ( Name and Password ) local on the phone using secure storage / IOS keychain. And then I want to pass the data from this storage to the corresponding fields on the page at the inAppBrowser.

Do you think this is possible, and if it is, how do I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the session structure in the server section of the site you open in the browser, you can enable auto login again. The browser in the Cordova is like a normal browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQLlite storage plugin in cordova it helps you to store your login details in device and lets you to redirect to your screen what you want to display

https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage